# Ruby regex in Yaml

Tags: ruby, cucumber, yaml

I'm new to YAML and I'm experimenting with writing some tests for language translation. The idea being that I have a YAML file that has the English and Welsh versions of the same text.  I was wondering how I might do the following use a regex within the string in the YAML?

Example:

I have this basic test:

```
#Gherkin
And I expect to see payment confirmation for "Dave"

#Step Def
    And /^I expect to see payment confirmation for "(.*?)"$/ do |user|
      expect(page).to have_text "Payment successful for #{user} - Reference: 000000"
end
```

YAML Entry:

```
"Payment successful for Dave reference: 000000"
 - welsh: "Taliad llwyddiannus ar gyfer Dave Cyfeirnod: 000000"
```

Could I parameterize Dave in that YAML entry as the test suite covers hundreds of users.

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain what you want a little better?
I'm not sure if you want to change the test to accommodate all possible YAML entries or make a YAML that can have interpolated text in it.

Also, the code example doesn't seem like valid RSpec syntax, could you update that also?

Comment: If possible, I'd like interpolated text in the YAML.  Using RSpec-Expectations within Capybara, that's the syntax for a simple text assertion on page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to interpolate text into YAML you will need to replace the words that you want to be interpolated with `%{keyword}` where the keyword is a key that will be used to indicate which data to interpolate there.

If you use Rails, you would use the `t` helper method as outlined in [this section of the I18n guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#passing-variables-to-translations).

```
# The YAML file
en:
  payment_succeeded: "Payment successful for %{first_name} reference: %{reference_number}"
wh: 
  payment_succeeded: "Taliad llwyddiannus ar gyfer %{first_name} Cyfeirnod: %{reference_number}"

# Rails Controller / View / Model
t(:payment_succeeded, first_name: 'Dave', reference_number: '000000')
```

If you want a pure ruby implementation you can use the `Kernel::format` method.

```
# The YAML file
# NOTE: This can be in any format, as long as you use %{keyword} in places where you want the data to be interpolated
translations:
  english: "Payment successful for %{first_name} reference: %{reference_number}"
  welsh: "Taliad llwyddiannus ar gyfer %{first_name} Cyfeirnod: %{reference_number}"

# Ruby
translations = YAML.load(File.read('translations.yaml'))
string = format(translations[:translations][:welsh], first_name: 'Dave', reference_number: '000000')
```

Hope this helps.